# Channel parameter error in Solspace tag cloud

Tags: solspace, solspace-tag, ee3

I am using v. 5.0.0 of the Solspace tag module in EE3, and when I use the channel parameter in the tag cloud, I get the following errors:

```
Notice

Undefined property: Tag::$sc
user/addons/tag/mod.tag.php, line 2331

Trying to get property of non-object
user/addons/tag/mod.tag.php, line 2331

Trying to get property of non-object
user/addons/tag/mod.tag.php, line 2331
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
{exp:tag:cloud tag_group_name="my_group" channel="my_channel1|my_channel2" orderby="tag_name" rank_by="entries" sort="asc" start="12" step="8" groups="5"}
<li><a href="{path="my_channel/my_group"}/{websafe_tag}" style="font-size: {step}px;" title="{tag}: {count} entries">{tag}</a></li>
{/exp:tag:cloud}
```

The above code worked with v. 4.2.9 & EE2. If I remove the channel="my_channel" parameter then the errors go away. I also noticed that the channel parameter is not listed in the current documentation or the 4.2.9 documentation, but it still worked before. Has this parameter been removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this error with Tag 5.0.0 in EE 3.0.0. This will be reported as a bug to our team. In the meantime, you can go in mod.tag.php and replace every mention of

```
$this->sc->db->channel_name
```

to

```
'channel_name'
```

There's about two places where this string is found in the file.